# Javascript forEach - TypeError: Cannot set property of undefined

Tags: javascript, foreach

I have the following Array, which I want to restructure

```
    {
        "feedId": 1,
        "status": "read",
        "count": 105
    },
    {
        "feedId": 2,
        "status": "read",
        "count": 46
    },
    {
        "feedId": 3,
        "status": "read",
        "count": 29
    }
```

When I use the following function I get the error TypeError: Cannot set property 'read' of undefined.

```
    var feeds = [];

    statusCountGrouped.forEach(function(item) {
        feeds[item.feedId][item.status] = item.count;
    });
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: You must initialize `feeds[item.feedId]` if it isn't yet created. You should learn to use the developer's tools of your browser, and especially the debugger, so that you'll be able to sort this kind of errors by yourself.

Comment: Because `feeds[item.feedId]` is `undefined`, as the error message indicates. Your problem can be simplified to `var feeds = []; feeds[0].read = 42;`, which produces the same error.

Comment: First of all, can you tell what you're trying to do? Or, what your final `feeds` array will look like?

Comment: how your new object look like?

Comment: do you want something like this. 
`statusCountGrouped = [{ "feedId": 1, "status": "read", "count": 105 }, { "feedId": 2, "status": "read", "count": 46 }, { "feedId": 3, "status": "read", "count": 29 }
]
var feeds = [];

feeds = statusCountGrouped.map(function (item) {
    return {
        [item.feedId]: {
            [item.status]: item.count
        }
    }
});
console.log(feeds)`

Comment: ```const feeds = [];

statusCountGrouped.forEach(function(item) {
    feeds.push({read: item.count});
});```
you can do like this as well if `feedId` is not a concern.

Answer (score 0):

**feeds[item.feedId]** isn't initialized. The simplest solution is to initialize in foreach if needed. I have two solutions, as you prefer:

1/

```js
const statusCountGrouped = [
  {
      "feedId": 1,
      "status": "read",
      "count": 105
  },
  {
      "feedId": 2,
      "status": "read",
      "count": 46
  },
  {
      "feedId": 3,
      "status": "read",
      "count": 29
  }
];

var feeds = [];

statusCountGrouped.forEach(function(item) {
    if(feeds[item.feedId] === undefined) { feeds[item.feedId] = {}; }
    feeds[item.feedId][item.status] = item.count;
});

console.log(feeds);
```

2/

```js
const statusCountGrouped = [
  {
      "feedId": 1,
      "status": "read",
      "count": 105
  },
  {
      "feedId": 2,
      "status": "read",
      "count": 46
  },
  {
      "feedId": 3,
      "status": "read",
      "count": 29
  }
];

var feeds = [];

statusCountGrouped.forEach(function(item) {
  feeds[item.feedId] = feeds[item.feedId] || {};
  feeds[item.feedId][item.status] = item.count;
});

console.log(feeds);
```

Comment: Thanks but this gives me the following output:      

"statusGrouped": [
        null,
        {
            "read": 105
        },
        null,
        {
            "read": 29
        }
    ],

Comment: The first null is here because you don't have a feedId that equals to 0 (And we're working on an array). I retried my code and i got  `[empty, {…}, {…}, {…}]` on my browser, so i don't know why the second null is here.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because `feeds[item.feedId]` is not defined before the assignment. You should initialize it before assigning a value to `feeds[item.feedId]`

```
var feeds = [];

i.forEach(function(item) {
    if (feeds[item.feedId] === undefined) feeds[item.feedId] = [];
    feeds[item.feedId][item.status] = item.count;
});
```

Hope this helps.